# what does "But enough about me" mean?

Tags: meaning

I want to know whether or not "but enough about me" is an idiom ? if yes, what does it mean? and when and how we can use it?

Comment: It means "I've been talking about myself for a while, here. I don't want to be selfish or perceived as self-centered, using all our time together talking only about me. Let's talk about something else now: maybe you!" and is often offered as an opportunity for *you* to talk about *yourself* for a bit. Or some other topic altogether.

Comment: it's just an often humorous way of saying "We have spoken enough about me. Let's now talk about you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an idiom.

You say that when you have been digressing, telling personal details/ facts. It means what it literally says: *"I have spoken enough about myself"*

Comment: It's an idiom in that it's extragrammatical and commonly used. It's  a very transparent idiom.